# How to secure <ice:messages /> tag to prevent XSS in Icefaces project?

Tags: jsf, xss, icefaces

I have the `<ice:messages />` to show the success or error when searching for something in an icefaces project. When I add the message I add something like  `"something wrong happened with search input " + searchinput`.
When entering something like `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` in the search input the response comes and alerts on the browser. Is there a way to prevent that.(I can't change what I return as a response due to some client requests )

I tried using `escape="true"` and it didn't work

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Perhaps the project has a custom renderer to allow HTML in messages in order to be able to use links and all?